# How to set a sink node for a network?

Tags: contiki, sink

I have been using the following piece of code for setting a node as sink node. Now, with this code only 1st node is set as sink. If I want to set the first node detected in the network, for instance, 3rd node as the sink node, then how to do so? Also, can you please explain the meaning of "if" statement in line 1, I think this would help me in solving the query.

1. if(rimeaddr_node_addr.u8[0] == 1 && rimeaddr_node_addr.u8[1] == 0)
2. {
3. printf("I am sink\n");
4. collect_set_sink(&tc, 1);
5. }

Comment: have you found any solution how to set a node as a sink?

Comment: No, did not find a solution yet.